# Tricky str value replacement within PANDAS DataFrame

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, replace

**Problem Overview**:

I am attempting to clean stock data loaded from CSV file into Pandas DataFrame. The indexing operation I perform works. If I call `print`, I can see the values I want are being pulled from the frame. However, when I try to replace the values, as shown in the screenshot, PANDAS ignores my request. Ultimately, I'm just trying to extract a value out of one column and move it to another. The PANDAS documentation suggests using the `.replace()` method, but that doesn't seem to be working with the operation I'm trying to perform.

Here's a pic of the [code and data before and after code is run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVfA3.png).

And the for loop (as referenced in the pic):

```
for i, j in zip(all_exchanges['MarketCap'], all_exchanges['MarketCapSym']):
    if 'M' in i: j = j.replace('n/a','M') 
    elif 'B' in i: j = j.replace('n/a','M')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all who posted. After thinking about your solutions and the problem a bit longer, I realized there might be a different approach. Instead of initializing a `MarketCapSym` column with `'n/a'`, I instead created that column as a copy of `MarketCap` and then extracted anything that wasn't an "M" or "B".

I was able to get the solution down to one line:

`all_exchanges['MarketCapSymbol'] = [ re.sub('[$.0-9]', '', i) for i in all_exchanges.loc[:,'MarketCap'] ]`

A breakdown of the solution is as follows:

1. `all_exchanges['MarketCapSymbol'] =` - Make a new column on the DataFrame called 'MarketCapSymbol.
2. `all_exchanges.loc[:,'MarketCap']` - Initialize the values in the new column to those in 'MarketCap'.
3. `re.sub('[$.0-9]', '', i) for i in` - Since all I want is the 'M' or 'B', apply `re.sub()` on each element, extracting `[$.0-9]` and leaving only the `M|B`.

Using a list comprehension this way seemed a bit more natural / readable to me in my limited experience with PANDAS. Let me know what you think!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `j` is a string, thus *immutable*.

You're replacing data, but not in the original dataset.

You have to do it another way, less elegant, without `zip` (I simplified your test BTW since it did the same on both conditions):

```
aem = all_exchanges['MarketCap']
aems = all_exchanges['MarketCapSym']

for i in range(min(len(aem),len(aems)): # like zip: shortest of both
     if 'M' in aem[i] or 'B' in aem[i]:
         aems[i] = aems[i].replace('n/a','M')
```

now you're replacing in the original dataset.

Answer (score 0):

If both columns are in the same dataframe, all_exchanges, iterate over the rows.

```
for i, row in enumerate ( all_exchanges ):
    # get whatever you want from row
    # using the index you should be able to set a value
    all_exchanges.loc[i, 'columnname'] = xyz
```

That should be the syntax of I remember ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html) is quite exhaustive tutorial on missing values and pandas. I suggest using [fillna()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df['MarketCap'].fillna('M', inplace=True)
df['MarketCapSym'].fillna('M', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid iterating if you can. As already pointed out, you're not modifying the original data. Index on the `MarketCap` column and perform the replace as follows.

```
# overwrites any data in the MarketCapSym column
all_exchanges.loc[(all_exchanges['MarketCap'].str.contains('M|B'),
                  'MarketCapSym'] = 'M'

# only replaces 'n/a'
all_exchanges.loc[(all_exchanges['MarketCap'].str.contains('M|B'),
                  'MarketCapSym'].replace({'n/a', 'M'}, inplace=True)
```